# CSS Position Absolute With Respect to a Parent Element Acting as Relative

Tags: css, css-position

In my long journey to update my CSS skills from the deprecated dust that they have turned into, I've been playing around with certain CSS properties —particularly z-index —I'm noticing something strange or maybe there's a certain condition.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mEpgR/

The element div1's parent is cont, I've made div1's position property set to absolute, yet when I shift it, it's moving relative to its parent. I was under the impression that items set to absolute positioning are outsider regular flow and move only relative to browser port as their parent.

What am I missing?

If the fiddle link does not work, code:

CSS:

```
.cont {
position:relative; 
height:200px;
top:200px; 
left:100px; 
background: green; width: 200px; 
}

.div1 {
background:red; 
position:absolute; 
top:50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cont">
<div class="div1">DIV1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is correct behavior. `position:absolute` will position an element *relative to the closest positioned ancestor*. To position it relative to the document, either remove `position:relative` from the parent, or move the  element out of the parent.

Comment: Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position

Comment: That's for the quick response; css behavior noted.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

An absolute positioned element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. Since you have it inside a parent with `relative` it will be absolutely positioned relative to this parent.

You might be looking for `fixed` position, which is relative to browser window.

Comment: here: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/ There's a graphic explanation of just that.